# how to build href in bootstrap-treeview?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, treeview

I'm using [bootstrap-treeview](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview) to display a tree-like view of my data. The initial and basic implementation is working but I need it to when I click the text value, i get redirected to the link.

The JS function that renders the tree is:

```
function initTree(treeData) {
    $('#treeview_json').treeview({
        data: treeData,
        enableLinks: true
    });
    // collapses all nodes
    $('#treeview_json').treeview('collapseAll', { silent: true });
}
```

The `enableLinks: true` node property renders the link. But I could not find any documentation or example on the `href` property.

Does the link has to be supplied with the data or can it be built by the javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass href as node attribute (see https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview#node-properties), so it is supplied with the data:

```
var tree = [
  {
    text: "Parent 1",
    nodes: [
      {
        text: "Child 1",
        nodes: [
          {
            text: "Google",
            href: "https://www.google.com"
          },
          {
            text: "Twitter",
            href: "https://www.twitter.com"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: "Facebook",
        href: "https://www.facebook.com"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/bvpncxko/

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to avoid hardcoding.

Comment: I was wondering if this can be done in Bootstrap V4,x? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Remember you must have enableLinks:true

```
function initTree(treeData) {
        $('#treeview_json').treeview({
            data: treeData,
            enableLinks: true,
        });
    }
```